# Jquery code not working for password confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Register</title>
 <style>
  .content{
   position: relative;
   top: 130px;
   border:3px solid black;
   padding: 50px;
   width:300px;
   margin: auto auto 200px auto;
   align: center;
   }
  
  body{
   background-image: url(Register.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
   }
  .s1{
   float:left;
   }
  .s2{
   float:right;
   }
  .s3 {
   margin-left: 110px;
   }
  .s4{
   margin-left: 90px;
   }
  .s4 a{
   color: black;
   font-size: 12;
   }
  .s4 a:hover{
   color: blue;
   }
  p{
   font-size: 12;
   color: red;    
   }
  .d1{
   margin-left:
   }
 </style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#pass , #pass1").on("keyup", function () {
   if ($("#pass").val() == $("#pass").val()) {
     $("#pass1").css("border", "3px solid green");
   } else 
     $("#pass1").css("border", "3px solid red");
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <jsp:include page="header.html"/>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="content">
   <form class="page" method="post" action="RegisterPage" name="register">
    <span class="s1">
     First Name
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" id="firstname" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Last Name
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" id="lastname" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Date of Birth
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input id = "input1" name="dob" type="date" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" id="date" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Gender
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input id = "input2" type="radio" name="gen" value="Male" required>Male 
     <input id = "input2" type="radio" name="gen" value="Female">Female 
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Membership Type
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input id = "input2" type="radio" name="mem" value="Librarian" required>Librarian
     <input id = "input2" type="radio" name="mem" value="Member">Member
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Address
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input name="addr" placeholder="Address First Line" id="addr" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Contact Number
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input id = "input1" name="c_no" type="number" placeholder="9999888777" id="c_no" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Email ID
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input name="loginID" type="email" placeholder="abc@def.com" id="loginID" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Username
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Password
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input name="password" type = "password" placeholder="Password" id="pass" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Confirm Password
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input name="password1" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="pass1" required>
    </span>
    <br>
    <div class="d1"><p>${error}</p></div>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s3"><input type="submit" value="Register" onClick="check()"></span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s4">
    <a href="Login.jsp">Already a user!! Login</a>
    </span>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
 <jsp:include page="footer.html"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Code not working properly.It is supposed to show **GREEN** border when the two passwords are equal and **RED** border when thy aren,t. But it is not working.I am working on eclipse **IDE**. Thanks in advance!!

I have tried changing the ids but it didn't work.  Does having different name and id effect the jquery statements?

Comment: #pass's value is probably always equal to #pass's value... (unless its NaN which it cant be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*your error :*

```
if ($("#pass").val() == $("#pass").val()) {
                               ^---------------------
```

**Change To:**

```
if ($("#pass").val() == $("#pass1").val()) {
                               ^---------------------
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#pass , #pass1").on("keyup", function () {
    if ($("#pass").val() == $("#pass1").val()) {
      $("#pass1").css("border", "3px solid green");
    }
    else 
      $("#pass1").css("border", "3px solid red");
  });
})
```

```css
.content{
   position: relative;
   top: 130px;
   border:3px solid black;
   padding: 50px;
   width:300px;
   margin: auto auto 200px auto;
   align: center;
   }
  
  body{
   background-image: url(Register.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
   }
  .s1{
   float:left;
   }
  .s2{
   float:right;
   }
  .s3 {
   margin-left: 110px;
   }
  .s4{
   margin-left: 90px;
   }
  .s4 a{
   color: black;
   font-size: 12;
   }
  .s4 a:hover{
   color: blue;
   }
  p{
   font-size: 12;
   color: red;    
   }
  .d1{
   margin-left:
   }
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<jsp:include page="header.html"/>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <form class="page" method="post" action="RegisterPage" name="register">
        <span class="s1">
          First Name
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" id="firstname" required>
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Last Name
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" id="lastname" required>
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Date of Birth
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input id = "input1" name="dob" type="date" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" id="date" required>
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Gender
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input id = "input2" type="radio" name="gen" value="Male" required>Male 
          <input id = "input2" type="radio" name="gen" value="Female">Female 
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Membership Type
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input id = "input2" type="radio" name="mem" value="Librarian" required>Librarian
          <input id = "input2" type="radio" name="mem" value="Member">Member
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Address
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input name="addr" placeholder="Address First Line" id="addr" required>
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Contact Number
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input id = "input1" name="c_no" type="number" placeholder="9999888777" id="c_no" required>
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Email ID
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input name="loginID" type="email" placeholder="abc@def.com" id="loginID" required>
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Username
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Password
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input name="password" type = "password" placeholder="Password" id="pass" required>
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Confirm Password
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input name="password1" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="pass1" required>
        </span>
        <br>
        <div class="d1"><p>${error}</p></div>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s3"><input type="submit" value="Register" onClick="check()"></span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s4">
        <a href="Login.jsp">Already a user!! Login</a>
        </span>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**you can use `input` event too,like this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#pass , #pass1").on("input", function () {
    if ($("#pass").val() == $("#pass1").val()) {
      $("#pass1").css("border", "3px solid green");
    }
    else 
      $("#pass1").css("border", "3px solid red");
  });
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#pass , #pass1").on("input", function () {
    if ($("#pass").val() == $("#pass1").val()) {
      $("#pass1").css("border", "3px solid green");
    }
    else 
      $("#pass1").css("border", "3px solid red");
  });
})
```

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  border:3px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  width:300px;
  margin: auto auto 200px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
    
body {
  background-image: url(Register.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.s1 {
  float:left;
}

.s2 {
  float:right;
}

.s3 {
  margin-left: 110px;
}

.s4 {
  margin-left: 90px;
}

.s4 a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12;
}

.s4 a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

p {
  font-size: 12;
  color: red;       
}

.d1{
  margin-left:
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<jsp:include page="header.html"/>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <form class="page" method="post" action="RegisterPage" name="register">
        <span class="s1">
          First Name
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" id="firstname" required>
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Last Name
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" id="lastname" required>
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Date of Birth
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input id = "input1" name="dob" type="date" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" id="date" required>
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Gender
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input id = "input2" type="radio" name="gen" value="Male" required>Male 
          <input id = "input2" type="radio" name="gen" value="Female">Female 
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Membership Type
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input id = "input2" type="radio" name="mem" value="Librarian" required>Librarian
          <input id = "input2" type="radio" name="mem" value="Member">Member
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Address
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input name="addr" placeholder="Address First Line" id="addr" required>
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Contact Number
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input id = "input1" name="c_no" type="number" placeholder="9999888777" id="c_no" required>
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Email ID
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input name="loginID" type="email" placeholder="abc@def.com" id="loginID" required>
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Username
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Password
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input name="password" type = "password" placeholder="Password" id="pass" required>
        </span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s1">
          Confirm Password
        </span>
        <span class="s2">
          <input name="password1" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="pass1" required>
        </span>
        <br>
        <div class="d1"><p>${error}</p></div>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s3"><input type="submit" value="Register" onClick="check()"></span>
        <br><br>
        <span class="s4">
        <a href="Login.jsp">Already a user!! Login</a>
        </span>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <jsp:include page="footer.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are matching with Pass word and confirm password, It must be:

```
if ($("#pass").val() == $("#pass1").val())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated working version of your code:

```js
$("#pass,#pass1").on("keyup", function() {
  if ($("#pass").val() == $("#pass1").val())
    $("#pass1").css("border", "3px solid green");
  else
    $("#pass1").css("border", "3px solid red");
});
```

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto auto 200px auto;
  align: center;
}

body {
  background-image: url(Register.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.s1 {
  float: left;
}

.s2 {
  float: right;
}

.s3 {
  margin-left: 110px;
}

.s4 {
  margin-left: 90px;
}

.s4 a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12;
}

.s4 a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

p {
  font-size: 12;
  color: red;
}

.d1 {
  margin-left:
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <form class="page" method="post" action="RegisterPage" name="register">
      <span class="s1">
First Name
</span>
      <span class="s2">
<input name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" id="firstname" required>
</span>
      <br><br>
      <span class="s1">
Last Name
</span>
      <span class="s2">
<input name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" id="lastname" required>
</span>
      <br><br>
      <span class="s1">
Date of Birth
</span>
      <span class="s2">
<input id = "input1" name="dob" type="date" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" id="date" required>
</span>
      <br><br>
      <span class="s1">
Gender
</span>
      <span class="s2">
<input id = "input2" type="radio" name="gen" value="Male" required>Male 
<input id = "input2" type="radio" name="gen" value="Female">Female 
</span>
      <br><br>
      <span class="s1">
Membership Type
</span>
      <span class="s2">
<input id = "input2" type="radio" name="mem" value="Librarian" required>Librarian
<input id = "input2" type="radio" name="mem" value="Member">Member
</span>
      <br><br>
      <span class="s1">
Address
</span>
      <span class="s2">
<input name="addr" placeholder="Address First Line" id="addr" required>
</span>
      <br><br>
      <span class="s1">
Contact Number
</span>
      <span class="s2">
<input id = "input1" name="c_no" type="number" placeholder="9999888777" id="c_no" required>
</span>
      <br><br>
      <span class="s1">
Email ID
</span>
      <span class="s2">
<input name="loginID" type="email" placeholder="abc@def.com" id="loginID" required>
</span>
      <br><br>
      <span class="s1">
Username
</span>
      <span class="s2">
<input name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
</span>
      <br><br>
      <span class="s1">
Password
</span>
      <span class="s2">
<input name="password" type = "password" placeholder="Password" id="pass" required>
</span>
      <br><br>
      <span class="s1">
Confirm Password
</span>
      <span class="s2">
<input name="password1" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="pass1" required>
</span>
      <br>
      <div class="d1">
        <p>${error}</p>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <span class="s3"><input type="submit" value="Register" onClick="check()"></span>
      <br><br>
      <span class="s4">
<a href="Login.jsp">Already a user!! Login</a>
</span>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one:

```js
$("#pass , #pass1").on("input", function () {

   if ($("#pass").val() == $("#pass1").val()) {
     $("#pass1").css("border", "3px solid green");
   } else 
     $("#pass1").css("border", "3px solid red");
 });
```

```css
.content{
   position: relative;
   top: 130px;
   border:3px solid black;
   padding: 50px;
   width:300px;
   margin: auto auto 200px auto;
   align: center;
   }
  
  body{
   background-image: url(Register.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
   }
  .s1{
   float:left;
   }
  .s2{
   float:right;
   }
  .s3 {
   margin-left: 110px;
   }
  .s4{
   margin-left: 90px;
   }
  .s4 a{
   color: black;
   font-size: 12;
   }
  .s4 a:hover{
   color: blue;
   }
  p{
   font-size: 12;
   color: red;    
   }
  .d1{
   margin-left:
   }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Register</title>
 <style>
  
 </style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <jsp:include page="header.html"/>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="content">
   <form class="page" method="post" action="RegisterPage" name="register">
    <span class="s1">
     First Name
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" id="firstname" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Last Name
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" id="lastname" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Date of Birth
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input id = "input1" name="dob" type="date" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" id="date" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Gender
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input id = "input2" type="radio" name="gen" value="Male" required>Male 
     <input id = "input2" type="radio" name="gen" value="Female">Female 
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Membership Type
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input id = "input2" type="radio" name="mem" value="Librarian" required>Librarian
     <input id = "input2" type="radio" name="mem" value="Member">Member
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Address
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input name="addr" placeholder="Address First Line" id="addr" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Contact Number
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input id = "input1" name="c_no" type="number" placeholder="9999888777" id="c_no" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Email ID
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input name="loginID" type="email" placeholder="abc@def.com" id="loginID" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Username
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Password
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input name="password" type = "password" placeholder="Password" id="pass" required>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s1">
     Confirm Password
    </span>
    <span class="s2">
     <input name="password1" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="pass1" required>
    </span>
    <br>
    <div class="d1"><p>${error}</p></div>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s3"><input type="submit" value="Register" onClick="check()"></span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="s4">
    <a href="Login.jsp">Already a user!! Login</a>
    </span>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
 <jsp:include page="footer.html"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Jatin it's working check properly press Password 1234 and confirm your password 1234 then your confirm password border changed into green other wise red.

Comment: its ]running fine in here but when i do the exact same thing in eclipse it doesn't work